# How do I query for all users that bought a license?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-digitalproducts

I’m trying to use Craft Commerce with the Digital Products plugin for a site where users can pay for being listed on that site.

Therefore I need to query for all users with certain criterias plus a valid license.

I’m not sure how to tackle this. I tried something like this, but it doesn’t work.

```
{% for user in craft.users({
    group: 'profiles',
    relatedTo: craft.digitalProducts.products({type: 'access'})
}) %}
```

Another approach would be to list all licenses, collect the related users and then list them. But that doesn’t seem like a good idea either, in terms of performance.

Any hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized that there is another way. No need for a custom plugin and shouldn’t be too heavy on the performance side of things.

```
{# Query for licenses, eager-load owner #}
{% set licenses = craft.digitalProducts.licenses.with(['owner']) %}

{# Collect owner ids #}
{% set licensedUserIds = [] %}

{% if licenses %}
    {% for license in licenses if license.userId %}
        {% set licensedUserIds = licensedUserIds|merge([license.userId]) %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{# Query for licensed users #}
{% set licensedUsers = craft.users({
    group: 'profiles',
    id: licensedUserIds
}) %}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's currently possible in as clean as manner as you'd like. I'd tackle the problem by writing a small plugin that queries the database and returns a list of user ids that match the criteria.

Remember, though, is that a license does not necessarily have a user id attached to it - a license must have either a user id or an email assigned to, so you might want to keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction. I had hoped that there might be a way already.